# Differentiating between links to have one page change based on the selected link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on rails and am making a web application with a show page that should just simply display the data in my database based on the link clicked. I want to make it where I can just have one page that changes based on which recipe I select but I cant figure out how to differentiate between the links.

Comment: Is your end goal to click on a recipe that leads to a page displaying info on that recipe?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want to happen I need to be able to query my database to only show info on the specific recipe that is clicked but to do that I need to be able to figure out what the title or id is of the recipe that is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic restful route to go to the **show action** of a controller.

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/recipes/:recipe_id', to: 'recipes_controller#show'
end
```

So your links could be something like: http://example.com/recipes/2
Which should load a page showing the information of the recipe with id 2

Now this is supposing you have a controller **recipes_controller.rb** with the **show** action to give you the info on that recipe

```
# app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def show
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])

    render 'show'
  end
end
```

Now in the `views/recipes/show.html.erb` template or whatever view you render in the **show** action, you will have access to a `<%= @recipe %>` containing the values of your object.

Comment: If you edit your question to include what you have tried, I could improve my answer to make it as close to your project as needed.